# can anyone out there help me for get solution while compiling ocr code in cygwin?

Tags: android

I want to make business card scanner application in android. I have these all dependence module

```
1) windows xp
2) cygwin (compiler)
3) eclipse
4) android-ndk
5) android-emulator
```

Now , the main problem is with the help of android ndk and cygwin when I compile ocr project . It gives me error like this :

```
 ld.exe : cannot find -ljpeg
```

plz help me to solve it. .I think i am very near to complete project. any help great appreciate. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that libjpeg doesn't seem to be installed in your cygwin environment.  You should either add it from the cygwin installer or compile/install from sources.  You can get source code here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg/files/libjpeg/6b/jpegsr6.zip - and compile/install it following the instructions in the install.doc file in the zip file.  After that you should be able to compile your project.

Comment: Hi Aleks, I successfully run cygwin installer to update all jpeg library . after that In cygwin folder my lib folder size is increased.  Inspite of that I have same error is there. plz help me . I think I am very near to my aim. .help me. .

Comment: Check that your libjpeg.* are in the library folder.  If not, then something is still missing.  Try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to include this lib directory.  If you're compiling from inside Eclipse, I think there's a setting somewhere inside the project settings where you can specify the location of external libraries.  Make sure that your lib directory (where your libjpeg libraries are) is included.

Comment: hi in lib folder there are 5 files based on libjpeg . there are      1) libjpeg.a 2)libjpeg.dll.a  3)libjpeg.la  4) libjpeg.map  5) libjpeg.txt . . .still there is a same error . .when i compile it with cygwin.

Comment: Did you check the settings in Eclipse?  I don't have access to a similar environment, so can't tell you exactly which settings to check.  Make sure the lib directory is in your PATH and define LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable BEFORE starting eclipse.

Comment: I cannot set any lib path in eclipase and any variable . . I know that the path is correct. .bcz all other file which in lib is compile successfully . . but only this error occur every time when i compile code in cygwin.